# Codemirror last line of textarea is unreadable and half cut off

Tags: codemirror

I am using CodeMirror https://codemirror.net/ to turn a textarea into editable code.

CodeMirror handles the resizing of the textarea, and it mostly works. But the last line of the text in the text area is half-cutoff.

[image: Chrome codemirror textarea showing the cutoff problem]

This problem does not happen when the codemirror CSS is allowed to operate alone, but when combining it with bootstrap css (et al), we get this problem.

Codemirror has lots of inscrutable options, and I am pretty sure one of them fixes this problem. Alternatively, it would be helpful to know which css style parameter or html parameter I should be fiddling with.

Where should I start solving this problem?